# How do I get at the bad guys during 'Caught in the Loop'

Tags: watch-dogs

I'm trying to complete Caught in the Loop, and the requirement to knock down rather than kill the enemies is really making things hard.

Right now I'm focusing on attacking while they're trapped in a narrow alley with blockers at the end. I can reliably get them out of their trucks, but as soon as I do, they go hostile, and I can make no progress.

**What effective strategies are there for completing Caught In The Loop?**

Comment: I cannot speak to this convoy specifically  because I don't remember which one it is. Usually, I have found, the best way to deal with them is to wait at the end of a narrow space, such as an ally or bridge. Park a car blocking their path and wait for them to all stop. Then pull out weapon of choice (mine is grenade launcher) and kill everyone. Obviously on the missions that require taking targets alive you will have to be more careful with your shots.

Comment: @adam This has been my strategy as well, but no luck so far.

Comment: Hm... Another option, that worked once or twice for me in the convoys that had multiple targets. Get a large car that can take a beating. Run it head first into the front most car. The rest of the enemies will get out. Drive back and forth running over people that are not the target. But personally I found the grenade launcher solution to be more consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My strategy for this mission was to take out as many as possible using the tech in the alleyway.

To do this, I'd run and grab a car and beat them to the alleyway. I'd park the car anywhere on the street, it doesn't matter where - you're not using it to block them.

Directly across from the alleyway is another walking area with some concrete gardens etc on the sides, you can hide behind one of these. From there, hack the cameras until you get to the one that's in the middle of the alleyway, you should be able to see the convoy coming.

Once the convoy reaches the alleyway, you should switch to the camera that overlooks the exit. When the lead car nearly reaches the exit, bring up the blockers. The lead car will back up over a transformer (?) in the ground that you can blow up - do this, blowing up the lead car.

Quickly switch to the rear cars and blow the devices near them. They should get out - one of the drivers will be carrying a cellphone you can explode. Do this, and it should take out the rear car and block the knock-down targets in. If you have trouble with this, plant some IEDs beforehand and use those.

From here, you'll have to shoot your way out. I was able to just wait for them to come to me and I could take them down with an assault rifle. The two knock-down targets waited in the alley, and I just had to sneak up close enough using cover to knock them down.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy I have found for this is taking them on one at a time.

By that I mean wait down a street where you are able to t-bone the enemies, Wen they are near race up the street (You need enough speed) and t-bone the back car. as soon as this happens hop out of your car and race over to their car. You should get there just before they get on there feet. Knock down that enemy.

Now hop in the car that they just hopped out of and take off. Do not stick around as you will be killed. They will chase you. Your goal now is to take out the other enemy (traffic lights work well for this) and again knock them down.

Switch to this enemies car again and high tail it outa there!

Answer (score 0):

Convoys are my least favorite missions. The way I do it is I slam my car into any of the enemy cars and the targets will usually get out and try to shoot you, so while others are chasing me, I drive not too far away, so all the convoy cars (except target) follows me, then I drive back and stop right next to the target and knock them out as soon as I get out of car.

Answer (score -1):

One easy way is to hack the things(eg. stream pipe) to eventually "kill" the target, that is considered a valid KO than gun shooting.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  It works on the other enemies, but not the targets.